# How everything will act in a world of two time dimensions?

Tags: time, universe, spacetime-dimensions

As far as we know , we live in a universe with only a single dimension of time, we know that some events happens *BEFORE* or *AFTER* other events , we know that some events happens *slower* or *faster* then others, but that is with a single dimension of time. What about another universe of two time dimensions, how will events be synchronized?

I don't think there will be the terms  *before* and *after* anymore in that universe, because as an analogy, we can order real numbers but we can't do the same with complex numbers (two axes).

But the terms *slower* and *faster* are probably still valid, because  length is measurable in any number of dimensions, (duration is length in time dimension).

Can any of you imagine such universe? How will particles interact?

**EDIT 1 :**

note here that many strange phenomenon will be intreduced , like time rotation !
also , events arround event in time => events in distance R arround it , in a circle
also time projection seems very strange , and linear functions in time plan

**EDIT 2 :**
I am not asking people to build a world for me , i am not writing a story/novel/movie ..., i am just trying to motivate others , and maybe inspire someone to make great art

Comment: Please don't use inline code blocks for formatting of prose. They look bad, and break tools like screen readers. I changed to italics instead.

Comment: You'd probably be better off trying Physics.SE for this

Comment: Considering events in this hypothetical universe will resemble two-dimensional planes instead of one-dimensional points in ours, it would be extremely difficult to imagine this world. I know of physicists who gave up working on models with multiple time dimensions. This is an interesting & challenging questions. It may be too difficult to answer here.

Comment: For sure all the developers of your world will be in foetal position when asked to code time-related applications.

Comment: @Goufalite you think i am making an application ? trust me i dont , i am just asking out of curiousity , and i wanned to share thats all

Comment: In which direction does time flow in your world? In ours, not only we have one dimension of time, we have a flow of time (we move forward in time and we cannot move back (yet)).

Comment: yeah i forgot to note , the time direction will be infinate .... or just they will be an angle for each world

Comment: So, a time based analysis would be something like Integral $t^2$ as t tends to infinity, before adding on whatever other variables there are? I really wouldn't want to work on that

Comment: Hello Hassen, and welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. Your question is great for discussing on the Factory Floor, the general chat for Worldbuilding. As a question however, it is suitable, This is because [you are asking us to build a world from your High Concept](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions) of two-dimensional time. The link explains why that is not a valid question. In brief: **we will assist you then you build your world**. We will not build your world for you, that is your job.

Comment: I am not building any world , i am just trying to motivate people , maybe someone there will be inspired and make a great art , i am trying to motivate others by this , thats all , if you want delete the questions ,thanks alot

Comment: Assuming that one cannot go backwards in time in either of your two time dimensions, your universe is likely to look much like this one from the POV of any observers, since they will only be able to experience a single linear time, even though that timeline may exist on a temporal plane. Think of it in terms of two spatial dimensions where you can only go in a direction which is a combination of North and East.

Comment: Yeah so you mean , instead of going forward or backward , you can go in an arbitrary angle , toward the future of both axes but sometimes in one faster than in the other

Answer (score 2):

I don't think people in their every-day lives would be able to tell the difference.

We think of time as a line but we don't perceive the line, we only perceive one point of it, which we call present. We remember the past because biology evolved memory, but we cannot access the past, just like we know there will be a future but we cannot access it. And even though there are a lot of different people perceiving it, we all agree that we perceive the same time. (History being different for different people is our doing, not the result of time going differently.) And the faraway objects we see around us in and outside our galaxy follow the same "time line", even if it is stretched or squashed due to relativistic physics. As far as we know, anyhow.

So who knows, time may already have two or more dimensions and our "time line" already describes a curve on a plane rather than a straight line. I think if someone discovered that time indeed has more dimensions, it will just remain an abstract to most people. In the same way most people know that relativity exists but no one has experienced time dilation as perceivable by human senses, so we don't think of it as something relevant to our every day life. Unless one has the job to program GPS or satelites, or research quantum physics.

Comment: I just saw a video with Stephen Hawkings about before the big bang.  He said that time does have more than the one dimension.  He didn't get into that aspect except to explain what was going on "before" the big bang.

Answer (score 0):

Your universe contains matter, time, and **all the possible outcomes of your universe !**

Let's image our friend [A Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland) (a drawing of a square) moving on a plane.

- stack other planes : you have the evolution of your square through **time**
- put other stacked planes nearby : you have **all the possible variations of moves of your square**

**Saw your edit**, same applies : imagine stacked planes that end up rejoining. The flatland is useful for making analogies of that kind

Of course this is opinion-based but it could give you an example. For how matter works, you could handwave it or see how time flows near black holes for example.

Interesting references :

- Groundhog day
- Steins;Gate

Answer (score 0):

Consider our world, with only one time dimension. You can only ever move in one direction through time, and it is forward. Such movement is "the arrow of time".

Consider that the two time dimensions are the axes of a cartesian graph. The arrow of time, for each particle in such a world, is a function.

Each coordinate in the graph is a moment in time. Now, because particles move through 2-dimensional time over a function, they may meet at different moments where the functions intersect each other. At those points, the particles are experiencing the same moment. Outside those points, they are experiencing different moments.

When you think of relativity and light cones it kinda makes you wonder whether that is not the case with our own universe, over sufficiently vast distances.